# Why will dmesg have message from user space?

Tags: linux, logging, kernel, init, dmesg

you can use dmesg -u to see log from userspace.
In my case, I have log from systemd and lvm. Why is this happening, why userspace program can print to kernel buffer ring?

Answer (score 2):

A root process can write to `/dev/kmsg`. This is used for logging that occurs very early, before regular logging systems are ready to do any logging.

Answer (score 0):

Some userspace processes can write to the dmesg because they execute actions which used to belong to kernel-space processes, but which have been moved to user-space to allow easier control by users.

A classic example is *udev*, which, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev):

> it handles ... all user space actions when adding/removing devices, including firmware load.

Another well-know example is [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), which is:

> Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE) is an operating system mechanism for Unix-like computer operating systems that lets non-privileged users create their own file systems without editing kernel code.

Together with *LVM, init*, and so on, these tools perform kernel operations in user space; for  this  reason, and possibly also for continuity with the instruments they replaced (devfs, hotplug, ...), their output clearly belongs in the kernel ring buffer.